# how to add another column for edit/delete button in django datatable?

Tags: django, datatables

Hello I'm try to learn django and have decided to read more about django and datatables.

Here is the link: https://github.com/shymonk/django-datatable

How would I add an edit/delete button to this datatable? Appreciate any help Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linkcolumn or link from his column list but you have to modify it
-- If you use this plugin you can use LinkColumn() or Link()